# How can get the browser version users use on mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser, mobile-website

During mobile web frontend development, how can get the browser version users use on mobile?
I want to get information about the 'samsung internet browser' and 'naver app' versions and do something different depending on the version they have installed.

Comment: `window.navigator.userAgent` might help you.

Comment: @CodeF0x Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.navigator` can get them.

Ref : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp